# webpack config for bootstrap fonts in react

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack

I have the following in my `webpack.config.js`

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy']
        }
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader"},
            { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
            { test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader:"url?prefix=font/&limit=5000" },
            { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
            { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  }
```

When I access my app's root and simply navigate via react-router the font and images for bootstrap work just fine. However, if I'm on a non-root path and refresh the browser, they are being loaded relative to that path. So instead of:

```
http://localhost:3000/fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158.woff
```

they are loaded as:

```
http://localhost:3000/brands/fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158.woff
```

which means I'm getting a 404 for each resource. I've been doing some research but I'm unsure what I might need to change so that these resources are always loaded absolute from the root path no matter what the app path is.

Comment: how are you loading the bootstrap css file?

Comment: It gets loaded as part of the bundle because of the css and sass loaders. Injected via javascript.

Comment: I'm fully open to loading it differently if someone has suggestions.

Comment: what about loading it directly in your index.html file and skipping the bundle?

Comment: I could do that, but I still would need a way to build the distribution, since I don't want to rely purely on external cdn. So I'd want to know how to instruct webpack to package it all up.

Comment: Can you show your `output` object (module.output)?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123175/discussion-between-jorge-obregon-and-gregg).

Answer (score 1):

Usually my `webpack.config.js` starts with the following. Try adding the `output`

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'webpack/hot/dev-server',
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
        './src/index',
    ],

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../../static/'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/build/'
    },

  // .... YOUR OTHER CONFIG HERE ....
}
```

And make sure to include `module.output.publicPath`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up changing my loader config for all the eot,woff, etc files to:

```
{
  test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpe?g|gif)(\?\S*)?$/,
  loader: 'url?limit=100000@name=[name][ext]'
}
```

I'm unsure yet as to why this fixed the problem, but I'm doing research on that. If I find out specifics, I'll report back to this answer.